# How to redirect traffic from one domain to another with Wordpress Redirection Plugin

Tags: regex, wordpress, redirect

I'm using the [Wordpress Redirection Plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/redirection/) on my site, and need to resolve a duplicate content issue by adding a 301 redirect from:

www.mysite.com

to:

www.mysite.org

NB: Both URLs share the same IP address, and the same content.

The redirect is currently working correctly for the root domain, but I also need to use a regular expression to ensure that all internal pages are also redirected to the same path on the new domain:

www.mysite.com/a-random-page/   -->   www.mysite.org/a-random-page/

Any pointers appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using Regular Expression:

Source URL: `http://www.example.com/(.*)`
Target URL: `http://www.example.org/$1`
Check the Regular Expression Box.

This will redirect `www.example.com/a-random-page/` to `www.example.org/a-random-page/`.